# ubuntu: facing problem in installing compass

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I want to compile a sass file but whenever I run this command:

```
$ compass compile
compass: command not found
```

And I tried to install compass by this command:

```
$ sudo gem install sass compass --pre --no-ri --no-rdoc
Successfully installed sass-3.3.0.alpha.121
    ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    compass requires sass (~> 3.2.5, runtime)
1 gem installed
```

and when I check the version of sass by `sass -v` it shows `Haml/Sass 2.2.17`.

so what should I do now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install compass with the package manager.

ruby-compass is in the universe repository, so make sure you have a

```
deb http://<your-server>/ubuntu/ <your-ubuntu-version> universe
```

line in your /etc/apt/sources.list

Next run:

```
sudo apt-get update; apt-get install ruby-compass
```

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: root@ubc-8-desktop:~# apt-get install ruby-compass
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package ruby-compass

Comment: Did you add the universe repository and a sudo apt-get update

Comment: In the mentioned file I have these: `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe`, `deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe`, `deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe`.  `lsb_release -a` shows `Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`. Meaning the version number `14.04.5 LTS` is mentioned nowhere in source.list file. Do I need to add this manually? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found on a [link](http://markushedlund.com/dev-tech/ubuntu-compass-command-not-found) to fix it just run this command on your terminal `echo "PATH=\$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:\$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin" >> /etc/profile.d/rubygems1.8.sh`

and restart my system. But it only run when I have root access so for root access rum `sudo-s` first.

And also command to install compass follow this [link](http://compass-style.org/help/) 
or quickely try this command
`gem install compass`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that `compass` was installed as `/usr/bin/compass.ruby2.1`

I created a  symbolic link from `/usr/bin/compass.ruby2.1` to `/usr/bin/compass` and it started working. I am not sure if it this is expected behavior or not.